# VBA excel how to get table number in for each word table

Tags: excel, vba, word-table

i have Word template with 3 table with empty cells. After code have finished i check if there is empty cell in each table and if table contains empty cells then code delete that table, but if table have data then i need to insert text above that table.
Each of that 3 table have they own specific text. So for word.document.tables(1) i need to put text "AAA", for word.document.tables(2) text "BBB"....

Problem is if i delete one table if is empty then that word document have 2 table and i need to delete table(3) so i get error that table(3) dont exist.

How can i get table count in for each loop?

Thanks!

```
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In wDoc.Tables
            If Len(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
                tbl.Delete
            Else
                wDoc.tbl.Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                wDoc.tbl.Range.Move wdParagraph, -1
                    If wDoc.Tables(b) = 1 Then
                        wDoc.Tables(b).Range.InsertBefore "AAA"
                    ElseIf wDoc.Tables(b) = 2 Then
                        wDoc.Tables(b).Range.InsertBefore "BBB"
                    ElseIf wDoc.Tables(b) = 3 Then
                        wDoc.Tables(b).Range.InsertBefore "CCC"
                    End If
            End If
Next tbl
```

Comment: Loop from the last table to the first perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop from the end of the Tables collection using a For loop eg

```
Dim tbl As Table, b As Long
For b = wDoc.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set tbl = wDoc.Tables.Item(b)

    If Len(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
        tbl.Delete
    Else
        tbl.Range.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        tbl.Range.Move wdParagraph, -1
        If b = 1 Then
            tbl.Range.InsertBefore "AAA"
        ElseIf b = 2 Then
            tbl.Range.InsertBefore "BBB"
        ElseIf b = 3 Then
            tbl.Range.InsertBefore "CCC"
        End If
    End If
Next b
```

You then have the Table index number in `b` and the Table object in `tbl`

Comment: That will work... Thank you!!